# The first element is missing when using Stream as input in wcf rest service C#

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, stream, streamreader

I have a wcf rest service with Stream as input parameter:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    void ImportStream(Stream data);
```

My code :

```
 public void ImportStream(Stream data)
    {
        if (data.ReadByte() != -1)
        {                
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(data))
            {                               
                string textRead = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
}
```

And this is my text as input in POSTMAN:

```
D_CA,P_AMOUNT,D_AN,D_PE,D_RU,D_ORU,D_AC,,D_GO,D_LE,D_NU,D_CO,D_MU,D_PMU,D_DP,P_COMMENT                              
A,100,,2019.12,S000,S000,XA1810,F00,PACK01,,S002,EUR,ORIG07-01,0000.PACKAGE,,,,,,2019.12,           
A,100,,2019.12,S000,S000,XA1810,F00,PACK01,,S004,EUR,ORIG07-01,0000.PACKAGE,,,,,,2019.12,
```

As result, I have textRead:

```
"_CA,P_AMOUNT,D_AN,D_PE,D_RU,D_ORU,D_AC,,D_GO,D_LE,D_NU,D_CO,D_MU,D_PMU,D_DP,P_COMMENT     ....... "
```

As you see the first Character 'D' is missing !?

How can I fix it ? Thanks

Comment: Well, you're reading the first byte from the `Stream`, and *then* passing the `Stream` to the `StreamReader`. The answer is surely... Don't read the first byte before passing the `Stream` to the `StreamReader`?

Comment: The ReadByte method will promote the position of the file pointer, moves one Byte forward. The StreamReader will read the stream after one byte position. As a result, the output string will lose one byte. In ASCII, one byte(8bit) usually represents one of  256 characters. Namely, one letter is missing. You can use the following method to determine the position of the pointer.       if (data.Position!= -1)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the `ReadBytes` if see the Documentation

> FileStream.ReadByte Method
>
> Reads a byte from the file and advances the read position one byte.

Set the stream position to the beginning of the file.

```
 public void ImportStream(Stream data)
    {
        if (data.ReadByte() != -1)
        {    
            data.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);            
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(data))
            {                               
                string textRead = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Note that `Length` is not always available

Comment: Not all streams are seekable

Comment: Thanks for your reply,I try your code but I have error on the line " data.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); " error : Specified method is not supported.